# How to create a random graph with parameters close to given ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have a list of parameters of a graph. Here they are:

```
number of nodes: 1882
radius: 15
diameter: 28
average clustering coefficient: 0.005066798238955518
average shortest path length: 11.748410823170731
number of connected components: 168
```

I also have empirical CDF of degree distribution:

```
'degree_cdf': [[0,
   1,
   2,
   3,
   4,
   5,
   6,
   7,
   8,
   9,
   10,
   11,
   12,
   13,
   14,
   15,
   16,
   17,
   19,
   21,
   24,
   46],
  [0.0,
   0.6902231668437833,
   0.8517534537725824,
   0.9086078639744952,
   0.9378320935175345,
   0.9516471838469713,
   0.9654622741764081,
   0.9723698193411264,
   0.9776833156216791,
   0.9808714133900106,
   0.9845908607863975,
   0.9888416578108395,
   0.9893730074388948,
   0.9925611052072264,
   0.9936238044633369,
   0.9952178533475027,
   0.9957492029755579,
   0.9968119022316685,
   0.997874601487779,
   0.9989373007438895,
   0.9994686503719448,
   1.0]]
```

I need to generate a random graph with parameters maximally close to those ones above. How could I define a corresponding graph? Is there any functions in networkx which would take any of those parameters as input data and create a corresponding graph?

Comment: I would wager that the best you can do is a network with the same degree distribution and a similar clustering coefficient. If you handle each component separately, then you can also match that number. [Relevant networkx docs here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.degree_seq).

Comment: However, (also) matching the radius/diameter and average shortest path length simultaneously will be hard. a) What is the desired trade-off between these criteria? What is the relative cost of \delta radius to \delta path length (to \delta clustering coefficient, etc)? b) These criteria are non-local properties of the graph. Local properties of the graph can be incrementally optimised for through rewiring. This is not the case for these measurements.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565401/2912349) is a related question and answer discussing a rewiring procedure to match the clustering coefficient in a graph with a given degree distribution.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I thought about using np.random.choice, since I have a number of nodes and cdf of degree distribution. but i don't understand how to do that